# Custom Authentication in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a web app in ASP.NET MVC from a base of current desktop app, but I need implement a custom form authentication for it. The issue is the code I'm using doesn't work, it don't authenticate the user at all.

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(UserModel user)
        {
            var databaseConnector = new MySQLConnector("localhost", "root", "", "ingeco_driverscontrol");
            IAuthManager authManager = new AuthDatabaseManager(databaseConnector);
            var password = user.Password;
            if (authManager.LogIn(user.Email, ref password))
            {
                var loggedUser = authManager.GetLoggedUser();
                var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, loggedUser.Email, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), false, "admin", FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                var hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

                if (ticket.IsPersistent)
                {
                    cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                }
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["ReturnUrl]"]))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(Request.Form["ReturnUrl]"].Split('/')[2]);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Not OK";
            }
            return View(user);
        }
```

What is wrong here? Why when I try to access an authorized action after the log in the current logged user still Anonymus?

Comment: Have you configured your web application to support forms authentication? If yes, show the code how you did that.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/forms-authentication-in-mvc/

Comment: You are right. I'd configured the form authentication but wrong. That was the issue. Thank you! and sorry